# Transferring domain out from Azure

Tags: azure, azure-ad-domain-services

I want to transfer a `.net` domain from Azure. I looked at the tutorials [here](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/09/22/2021-Managing-ASD.html) and [here](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2017/08/08/FAQ-App-Service-Domain-and-Custom-Domains#transfer-domain-out) but I could not get the authorization code and could not get to the Advance Management for the domain. In the past I found that I need to go to the Advanced Management Portal for the domain but it was grayed out and no it is missing.

Also I saw [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/20a9fd90-8ee4-45b0-b3f1-ead24c0130de/dns-transfer-out?forum=windowsazuremanagement) that I need to remove the domain from its App, I tried it and it didn't help

What should I do to transfer the domain? How can I unlock it?

Thanks,
Ido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advanced managment portal is available on this URL: https://dcc.secureserver.net/domains

My Azure login email wasn't recognised as a valid username, use "Need to find your username" and follow the instructions, the result was a numeric ID customer #.

Use "Need to find your password" to reset the password for that customer #.

Login using the new details.